# opencv: Exact polygon of contour

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Based on the following binary image, I'm trying to get a polygon of the outer contour. (This is already processed and looks promising).

[image]

Now, I want to get an exact polygon of the outer contours / border, but using the `polylines` / `fillPoly` methods yield very unprecise polygons:

[image]

(Here is the polygon / original overlapped):

[image]

How can I get a more precise polygon? See especially the bottom left corner, where the border and the polygon don't match at all

Code so far (based mainly on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74092934/opencv2-findcontours-can-i-get-just-one-big-external-contour-the-image-has-se):

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img_color = cv2.imread('carved.png')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_color, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imwrite('ex1_gray.png', img_gray)
img_binary = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img_gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)
cv2.imwrite('ex1_binary.png', img_binary)

points = np.column_stack(np.where(img_binary.transpose() > 0))

# draw white filled hull polygon on black background
mask = np.zeros_like(img_binary)
cv2.fillPoly(mask, [points], 255)
cv2.imwrite('ex1_zeroslike.png', mask)

# get the largest contour from result2
contours = cv2.findContours(img_binary, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# draw contour on copy of input
contr = cv2.cvtColor(img_binary.copy(), cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
contr = cv2.drawContours(contr, [big_contour], 0, (0,0,255), 2)

cv2.imwrite('ex1_convex_hull_contour.png', contr)
```

I checked the `fillPoly` method but it doesn't seem that there is a parameter for this. Changing `lineType` had no effect.

Comment: The black and white image, is that img_binary or img_gray? You are already using cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, so you should already get the pixel-perfecf contour from your binary input. Can you verify that img_binary is as fine as you need it?

Comment: morphology operation before findContours. -- source data please. your mask is already broken. avoid having to fix it up.

Comment: The original is here: https://i.imgur.com/hHSyLVC.png, I used carvekit (https://github.com/OPHoperHPO/image-background-remove-tool) to preprocess it (remove the background) so the "carved.png" in the code is this: https://i.imgur.com/ub7CvBQ.png

Comment: @Micka I'm not sure I understand your question. The first (black & white) image is img_binary. It was created from the carved by converting to grayscale and executing `cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img_gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)`. img_gray is never used after that

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thanks for the hint, using dilation on the binary image seems to improve the polygon

Comment: there is mention of "captcha" in the picture. good luck trying to apply traditional image processing on modern captchas. that has a chance of working if the people that came up with the captcha haven't had to deal with AI yet.